# Configuring multiple websites on a single Apache instance

Tags: apache

I am looking for a way to host multiple websites on a single server. Currently I have used reverse proxy to host two of the websites using the following method:

I have a php site in /var/www/html folder and a nodejs app running on localhost:3015. My apache2 config is like following:-

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName site1.example.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:3015/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3015/
        ServerName site2.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Now I further want to host few old websites at:

site1.example.com/archives/2014, 13 and so on

site2.example.com/archives/2014, 13 and so on.

In case of site1.example.com I can use alias as the site hosted is a php site. 
In the second case where I am using reverse proxy what will be the best way to host a php site.

Also, please suggest a way where new sites can be easily added and the old sites can be moved to archived folder. These site might be on django, ROR and so on.

Is this even possible?

Comment: You should be able to just copy the proxy stanza, change the name and the port...

Comment: I cannot have site1.example.com/archive/2014 as servername. Is there any other option I can use with proxy to map the url to another port.

Comment: try ProxyPass / http://localhost:<port>/archive/2014  and ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:<port>/archive/2014  I haven't done that but it might work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out a way to do the same. What you need to do is host all the sites at different port:

```
site1 => 3015
site2 => 4015

site3 => 3014
site4 => 4014

and so on.
```

Now you can configure your default.conf in apache2 as following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>    
        ProxyPreserveHost On

        ProxyPass /archive/2014/ http://localhost:3014/
        ProxyPassReverse /archive/2014/ http://localhost:3014/

        ProxyPass / http://localhost:3015/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3015/

        ServerName site1.example.com    
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ProxyPreserveHost On

        ProxyPass /archive/2014/ http://localhost:4014/
        ProxyPassReverse /archive/2014/ http://localhost:4014/

        ProxyPass / http://localhost:4015/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:4015/

        ServerName site2.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

This will work for sites on any platform, currently my site3 and site4 are php and site1 and site2 are node and django respectively. You might need to play with urls and links a little to make everything work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be quite what you are asking for, but give this a try. It's a variation on the Apache config I use in a dev VM, which is set up for wildcard domain hosting. I haven't tested this config specifically, but you should be able to tweak it to suit your needs.

This essentially tells Apache how to find sites such as:

- `site1.example.com => /var/www/html/site1/public_html`
- `site2.example.com => /var/www/html/site1/public_html`
- `2014.archive.site1.example.com => /var/www/html/site1/public_html/archives/2014`

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName example.com
      ServerAlias *.example.com
      ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
      DocumentRoot /var/www/html

      <Directory />
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
          AllowOverride All
          Order allow,deny
          allow from all
      </Directory>

      <Directory /var/www/html>
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
          AllowOverride All
          Order allow,deny
          allow from all
      </Directory>

      DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

      RewriteEngine on

      RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower

      # *.example.com
      RewriteCond ${lowercase:%{SERVER_NAME}} ^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.example\.com$
      RewriteRule ^(.+) ${lowercase:%{SERVER_NAME}}$1 [C]
      RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.example\.com/(.*) /var/www/html/$1/public_html/$2 

      # *.archive.*.example.com
      RewriteCond ${lowercase:%{SERVER_NAME}} ^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.archive\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.example\.com$
      RewriteRule ^(.+) ${lowercase:%{SERVER_NAME}}$1 [C]
      RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.archive\.([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.example\.com/(.*) /var/www/html/$2/public_html/archives/$1/$3
  </VirtualHost>
  ```

If this isn't what you were asking for, let me know.

Comment: The issue I am facing is these sites are made on different platforms. For example, the node.js app runs on localhost:3015. Now any request which comes to site2.example.com goes to localhost:3015. How can I make sure through apache that request coming with site2.example.com/archive/2014 should go somewhere else instead of localhost:3015